# Implementing a site search engine that searches static pages

Tags: php, javascript, search, search-engine

What I would like to accomplish is to integrate a search feature into my website that is capable of searching my web pages that are static(content does not change). I need the search engine to be free to use and must operate using JavaScript or PHP (and MySQL if needed). I have tried looking on Google (if anyone is wondering) , but maybe I'm just not searching for the right thing. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel - use Google Custom Search: http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does sound like a rather great idea. I am slightly confused on the big difference between google custom search and google site search. They seem to do the same thing. Mind elaborating on the differences slightly?

Comment: The differences are cosmetic mostly. You have more control over the appearance of the results, and the ads.

Comment: problem with google custom search is that it fills half your search result screen with ads.

Answer (score 6):

```
i got something today , so updating for other users
```

**Google Internal Site Search script (JavaScript, free)**
Need a powerful internal search engine script to allow visitors to search the contents of your site? This script uses Google to enable comprehensive search on your site. Cut and paste installation that works on any type of sites.

**Sphider (PHP, free)**
Sphider is a lightweight web spider and search engine written in PHP, using MySQL as its back end database. It is suitable for adding search functionality to small or medium sites (up to around 20,000 pages). It also works great as a tool for site analysis - finding broken links, gathering statistics about the site etc.

**TSEP (PHP, free)**
TSEP is a search engine for a website for your website! You can put a "Search this site" anywhere on your website and let people quickly find what they are looking for.

**Zoom Search Engine (PHP, commercial $49-$99)**
Zoom is a robust PHP script for adding powerful custom search engine to your website, intranet, or CD/DVD.

**Perlfect Search (Perl, free)**
An integrated, general purpose, site indexer and search engine. It comes as a pair of distinct scripts. The indexer, that automatically, scans and indexes a web site, and the search engine, a cgi script that serves search queries for keywords over the index, and displays results pages in html, in a standard format including title, description and relevance ranking for each matching document.

**CGIWorld Site Search (Perl, commercial $25)**
SiteSearch gives you the ability to search your website quickly & easily by the use of the password protected browser based administration area. Set the path of the directory you want searched, set the files & directories you want searched, and also the directories & files you do not want searched. SiteSearch is a great tool for the average website of around or below 500 pages.

**Fluid Dynamics Search Engine (Perl, free and commercial versions)**
FDSE is an easy-to-install search engine for local and remote sites. It returns fast, accurate results from a template-driven architecture. Freeware and shareware versions are available with Perl source.

**ASP Site Search (ASP, free)**
This ASP Site Search application is commented on each line of code to make it easier for a beginner to follow or to customise. The Site Search application comes in two versions the Advanced version has more functions but requires that the web server has the VB Scripting Engine 5 or above installed.

**Site Search Pro (ASP, commercial)**
Site Search Pro 2.0 is comprehensive search script for ASP or PHP site

Refer : http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/search2.shtml

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at this. (For anyone who struggles their way through this problem)

**JSE internal seach engine**

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jse/

Uses regular expressions to efficiently and rapidly search the index for matches based on the entered keywords. Supports basic logic (ie: negation).

Returns the results on a seperate page from the search form itself, neatly formatted. Uses session cookies to transmit the query between the two pages.

Stores the index (url, keywords and description for each page you wish to be "crawled") in the "results" page. This means the index is loaded only when a search has actually been performed, saving on bandwidth and download time.

Searches title, description and desingated keywords within the index for a match.

Answer (score 1):

"Sphider is a lightweight web spider and search engine written in PHP, using MySQL as its back end database. It is a great tool for adding search functionality to your web site or building your custom search engine. Sphider is small, easy to set up and modify, and is used in thousands of websites across the world."

http://www.sphider.eu/

Comment: Thank you, however I noticed that i't hasn't been updated in 2 years. I am a bit concerned that it may have quite a few glitches by now sine the php language has changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, anyway I would suggest Tipue-search.
Its pure javascript and can be integrated with any page.

https://github.com/Tipue/Tipue-Search

Answer (score 0):

Swiftype is another more recent addition to the market too: https://swiftype.com/